# How to control the width of a recyclerview object

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

So im building and app for school abour series and movies and Im using recyclerview, but each card ocuppies the full with of the screen and then scrolls right and left:
[image]

i've search all over internet and no idea how to get it to work like: [image]

My recycler_view.xml is the following:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:maxWidth="250dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_image"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:maxWidth="250dp"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        android:minWidth="250dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|start"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Some date"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|start"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="5"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and my main layout:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.juanfri.pruebareclyclerview.MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewPeliculas"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Peliculas"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.064" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewSeries"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Series"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerViewPeliculas" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewPeliculas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewPeliculas"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewSeries"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewSeries" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this my recycler adapter I might have to change it here but no idea:

```html
package com.example.juanfri.pruebareclyclerview;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Juanfri on 28/05/2017.
 */

public class RecyclerAdapterPelicula extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapterPelicula.PeliHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Pelicula> mPeliculas;
    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapterPelicula.PeliHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View inflatedView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_card, viewGroup, false);
        return new PeliHolder(inflatedView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerAdapterPelicula.PeliHolder holder, int i) {
        Pelicula itemPhoto = mPeliculas.get(i);
        holder.bindPhoto(itemPhoto);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mPeliculas.size();
    }

    public RecyclerAdapterPelicula(ArrayList<Pelicula> Peliculas) {
        mPeliculas = Peliculas;
    }
    public static class PeliHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        //2
        private ImageView mItemImage;
        private TextView mItemDate;
        private TextView mItemDescription;
        private Pelicula peli;

        //3
        private static final String PHOTO_KEY = "PHOTO";

        //4
        public PeliHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

            mItemImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
            mItemDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_date);
            mItemDescription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_description);
            v.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        //5
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /*Context context = itemView.getContext();
            Intent showPhotoIntent = new Intent(context, Pelicula.class);
            showPhotoIntent.putExtra(PHOTO_KEY, peli);
            context.startActivity(showPhotoIntent);*/
        }
        public void bindPhoto(Pelicula mpeli) {
            peli = mpeli;
            Picasso.with(mItemImage.getContext()).load(mpeli.getPoster()).into(mItemImage);
            mItemDate.setText(peli.getNombrePelicula());
            mItemDescription.setText(Integer.toString(peli.getDuracion()));
        }
    }
}
```

I really don't need a solution just a clue on how to move forward -.-"

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** Use root `LinearLayout` width as `wrap_content` or `250dp`.

**2.** Remove attribute `layout_weight` from `ImageView` and `TextView's`.

**3.** Use attribute `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:gravity="center"` to `TextView` to keep `text` position at `center`.

**4.** Remove unnecessary max-min height/width from `ImageView`.

**Here is the working code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxWidth="250dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_image"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/dummy"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="Big Bang Theory"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textColor="#727272"
        android:text="2154"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 1):

you have to set gravity for `textView` the same for `imageView` and i would suggest this behaviors for your layout :

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:maxWidth="250dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_image"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:maxWidth="250dp"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        android:minWidth="250dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Some date"
        android:layout_below="@id/item_image"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:layout_below="@id/item_date"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:maxWidth="250dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_image"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:maxWidth="250dp"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        android:minWidth="250dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|start"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Some date"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|start"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="5"/>
</LinearLayout>
```